# TimescaleDB time_bucket_gapfill: locf prev argument

Tags: sql, postgresql, iot, timescaledb

I have a timescale database with a table consisting of IoT device data:

```
value (Integer) | device_id (ForeignKey) | time (timestamp with timezone)
5               | device_1               | 2023-01-01 13:21:32+00
10              | device_2               | 2023-01-01 13:21:32+00
7               | device_1               | 2023-01-01 13:26:32+00
9               | device_2               | 2023-01-01 13:26:32+00
...
```

with new values being inserted every 5 minutes for each device.

I want to create a list of 100 datapoints to create a line diagram of all data within a given time range and a given set of devices. So I've decided to divide the time range into 100 even intervals, calculate the average value for all values within an interval for each device and sum up all average values for each interval.But if there is no data in an interval for a device, the latest value within the last 10 minutes should be used, otherwise 0.

So far I've come up with the following query:

```
SELECT bucket as time, sum(avg_per_device.avg_value) as energy FROM 
(
    SELECT
        time_bucket_gapfill(
            INTERVAL_LENGTH,
            time,
            start => START_TIMESTAMP,
            finish => END_TIMESTAMP
        ) AS bucket,
        locf(
            avg(value)
        ) as avg_value,
        device_id
        FROM data as d1
        WHERE
            device_id = ANY([DEVICES...]) AND
            time >= START_TIMESTAMP - '10 min'::interval AND time <= END_TIMESTAMP
       GROUP BY bucket, d1.device_id
) AS avg_per_device
GROUP BY bucket
ORDER BY bucket ASC
```

The result is something like this:

```
value | time
15    | 2023-01-01 13:21:32+00
16    | 2023-01-01 13:26:32+00
...
```

`time` being the start time of a bucket and `value` being the sum of all average values for each device and bucket . I haven't found a way though to use the latest value in the last 10 minutes. I've tried to use the [prev](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hyperfunctions/gapfilling/time_bucket_gapfill/#locf) argument with no success, because there seems to be no reference to the *current* bucket start time so that I can filter the data for the latest value in the last 10 minutes with something like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(value, 0)
FROM data
WHERE time < current_bucket_start
SORT BY time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Is there any way to reproduce this behavior in timescale?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `first` and `last` functions with the  second argument that is `time`.

```sql
SELECT bucket as time, sum(avg_per_device.avg_value) as energy FROM 
(
    SELECT
        time_bucket_gapfill(
            INTERVAL_LENGTH,
            time,
            start => START_TIMESTAMP,
            finish => END_TIMESTAMP
        ) AS bucket,
        locf(
            avg(value)
        ) as avg_value,
        last(value,time) as last_value,
        device_id
        FROM data as d1
        WHERE
            device_id = ANY([DEVICES...]) AND
            time >= START_TIMESTAMP - '10 min'::interval AND time <= END_TIMESTAMP
       GROUP BY bucket, d1.device_id
) AS avg_per_device
GROUP BY bucket
ORDER BY bucket ASC
```